# .htaccess Redirect with RegEx not working - "No input file specified."

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a Wordpress blog on my domain that was set up by a different web admin. All of the posts are filed under this file structure:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/index.php/2012/04/24/name-of-the-post/
```

I am trying to use my .htaccess file to 301 Redirect links to the old posts, to their new address seen here (notice it is the same URL, except with the `/index.php` missing):

```
http://www.example.com/blog/2012/04/24/name-of-the-post/
```

In my .htaccess file, I am trying to redirect the URLs with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/index\.php/([A-Za-z0-9-/.]+)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1 [R=301]
```

**QUESTION**: When I use the above RegEx in my .htaccess file, I get an error **"No input file specified."**  in the browser, and the Redirect does not happen. What am I doing wrong? Is there a problem with my Regular Expression? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Where do you see such error? Who generates it -- WordPress or Apache? Can you check Apache's error log for **exact** error message, please.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. It looks like it's generating from the server because it is a completely blank white window other than the error message. I do not believe it is being produced by Wordpress.

Comment: The please check Apache's error log -- it should have exact description if it was generated by Apache.

Comment: Well -- ask your hosting company .. but it should be available to you in Control Panel under Logs section .. as well as accessing it via FTP (sometimes) -- usually file will be called `error.log`.

Comment: Try using a more simple regex for matching, like `^blog/index\.php/(.+)$` and tell us if this changes anything

Comment: @TomKnapen I tried that implementation as well, with no success. The site is hosted at GoDaddy and apparently (from what I can find on Google) it's an issue with how their servers handle mod_rewrite. I found this http://www.kernelbd.com/blog/web-applications/htaccess-mod_rewrite-issue-no-input-file-specified-solution/ but it does not work for me :(

Comment: Change your rule to: `RewriteRule ^blog/index\.php/(.*)$ blog/$1 [R=301,L,NC]` and see if that works?

Comment: @anubhava this also gives me the "No input file specified." error.

Comment: I suspect you're getting this error from your php code. Can you check your error.log of Apache as well.

Comment: Please provide all of your current htaccess code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was that I needed to place an .htaccess file into my `blog` directory.

Here's the code that worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L,NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```